# Guidelines for PII data in use in cloud

Tags: cloud, pci-compliance, pii

There are guidelines on PII data in transit and at rest. What are the guidelines on using PII data in plain text in the logic? (in use at runtime)

Answer (score 0):

https://confidentialcomputing.io/ - this initiative could very well address the usage of secure data in use. Attempts to providing a fully encrypted life cycle for sensitive data.